# Spring Batch does not write and accepts using FlatFileItemWriter<List<MainDTO>>

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am really hoping anybody can answer my question regarding Spring Batch writer.

My goal is:

- Read all data from Parent table
- Process the data from reader and the results is store to common DTO like this:

```java
public class CommonDTO{

    private ParentDTO parentDTO;
    private List<Child1DTO> child1DTOList;
    private List<Child2DTO> child2DTOList;
}
```

These DTOs have data after process.

Problem starts when I write these files into `.dat` file. There should be 3 generated `.dat` files upon calling the writer.

- `ParentDTO` should be generated to exclusive 1 `.dat` file.
- `child1DTOList` should be generated to exclusive to another 1 `.dat` file.
- `child2DTOList` should be generated to exclusive to another 1 `.dat` file.

`child1DTOList` and `child2DTOList` are dependent base on `ParentDTO` data specifically the primary IDs from reader.

Database design:

**Parent Table Fields:** Primary ID

**Child 1 Table Fields:** Foreign Key from Parent Table(can be more than 1, that's why I am returning list in processor.

**Child 2 Table Fields**: Foreign Key from Parent Table(can be more than 1, that's why I am returning list in processor.

How should I design the writer in order to generate 3 `.dat` files?
I am using `FlatFileItemWriter<List<Child1DTO>>` but its not really working and writing.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am using `FlatFileItemWriter<List<Child1DTO>>` but its not really working and generating `.dat` files.
I can redesign my implementation if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding Bean for each children, please add this part of code, If there is problem please send here Error messages.

```
public class CommonDTOItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CommonDTO> {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemWriter<ParentDTO> parentWriter;

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemWriter<Child1DTO> child1Writer;

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemWriter<Child2DTO> child2Writer;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CommonDTO> items) throws Exception {
        for (CommonDTO item : items) {
            // Write parentDTO to parent.dat
            parentWriter.write(Arrays.asList(item.getParentDTO()));

            
            child1Writer.write(item.getChild1DTOList());

            
            child2Writer.write(item.getChild2DTOList());
        }
    }
}
```

And add this part if you mis :

```
public class Child1DTOItemWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter<Child1DTO> {

    @Value("${output.file.path}")
    private String outputPath;

    private String filename;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        filename = outputPath + "child1DTO_" + stepExecution.getStepName() + ".dat";
        this.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filename));
        this.setAppendAllowed(true);
        this.setHeaderCallback(writer -> writer.write("Header line"));
        this.setFooterCallback(writer -> writer.write("Footer line"));
        this.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
        this.open(stepExecution.getExecutionContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Child1DTO> items) throws Exception {
       
        super.write(items);
    }
}
```

add in properties file also :

```
output.file.path=output/

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<ParentDTO> parentDTOFlatFileItemWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['output.file.path']}") String filePath) {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<ParentDTO>()
            .name("parentDTOFlatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath + "/parentDTO.dat"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(",")
            .names("parentField1", "parentField2", "parentField3") // replace with your actual field names
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<List<Child1DTO>> child1DTOFlatFileItemWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['output.file.path']}") String filePath) {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<List<Child1DTO>>()
            .name("child1DTOFlatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath + "/child1DTO.dat"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(",")
            .names("child1Field1", "child1Field2", "child1Field3") // replace with your actual field names
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<List<Child2DTO>> child2DTOFlatFileItemWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['output.file.path']}") String filePath) {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<List<Child2DTO>>()
            .name("child2DTOFlatFileItemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath + "/child2DTO.dat"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(",")
            .names("child2Field1", "child2Field2", "child2Field3") // replace with your actual field names
            .build();
}
```

Comment: 2023-03-04T21:55:44,933 ERROR [main] m.e.n.b.c.p.LogErrorsAndSkipItemSkipPolicy: org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractFileItemWriter.write(AbstractFileItemWriter.java:239)

Comment: Please look the modified answer : @angelprincess

Comment: The method getExecutionContext() is undefined for the type StepExecution

Comment: Make sure you are importing the correct StepExecution class from the Spring Batch library, which is org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution. @angelprincess

Comment: Error: The method writer(ItemWriter<? super List<Child1DTO>>) in the type SimpleStepBuilder<ReaderDTO,List<Child1DTO>> is not applicable for the arguments (Child1DTOItemWriter)

Comment: Upon calling this writer: 

.writer(child1DTOItemWriter())  
  (@)Bean
  (@)StepScope
  public Child1DTOItemWriter child1DTOItemWriter() {
   return new child1DTOItemWriter();
  }

Comment: if Child1DTOItemWriter does not implement the ItemWriter<? super List<Child1DTO>> interface. Make sure that Child1DTOItemWriter implements this interface, or extends a class that implements it.

Comment: Try changing the writer(child1DTOItemWriter()) to writer(child1DTOitemWriter()) to match the method name.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of the ItemWriter interface in your project, and the SimpleStepBuilder is expecting a different version.

Comment: Can you vote up my answer @angelprincess

Answer (score 0):

you should write different Bean for different files.

For example :

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Child1DTO> child1Writer() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Child1DTO> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("child1.dat"));
    writer.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: I already did this but for the case of child DTOs, FlatFileItemWriter cannot write since it is a list. Example: FlatFileItemWriter<List<Child1DTO> is error since I think because it is a list. Do you have any idea how to use FlatFileItemWriter  with list as an input?

Comment: If my answer is helped you please let me know ?